# Does IBM Bluemix Object Storage service support expiring objects?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

According to Swift docs https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/overview_expiring_objects.html adding X-Delete-After header to a PUT or POST object will make it expire after the seconds passed in that value.

Is this feature supported in IBM Bluemix Object Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IBM Bluemix Object Storage](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/index.html) supports expiring objects, i.e., automatic deletion. You can use the `X-Delete-At` or `X-Delete-After` header attributes that you mentioned in your question. As usual, this is found in the [documentation for IBM Bluemix Object Storage under "Managing Objects"](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/os_deletion.html).

The `X-Delete-At` uses epoch time and this command (taken from the docs) would have deleted the object at "2016/04/01 08:00:00":

```
swift post -H "X-Delete-At:1459515600" container1 file7
```